# Determining absolute number of bytes used on ARM stack after calling function?

Tags: assembly, stack, arm, depth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make my c code safe from stack overflows on my Raspberry Pi. I am a beginner to this so bear with me for a bit. I was told that one way to determine the amount of bytes used by calling a function is to initialize space on the stack by filling it with know values (such as 0xff). Then run the function and then search backwards to see how many of the stack was changed from the known values. By taking the original stack depth and the stack depth at before the first unchanged value, I can determine the amount of stack that was used by that function. Sounded reasonable to me.

My problem is that this assembly stuff is really confusing to me. I have been reading that I can embed ARM assembly code in my c code by using asm(), but I am unsure how to initialize the stack memory and then go back through and check it. Is there a resource I can look at that would help out? I know so little about assembly that I don't even know how to form a very good search term.

Thanks.

Comment: if you are talking about a single function just look at the disassembly.  Also note that compile options will vary stack usage.

Answer (score 2):

this should be very easy to do in asm provided you have a good idea how deep you can safely go (you can even pass that in as an argument)

```
.globl fill_stack
fill_stack:
  mov r2,sp
  mvn r3,#0
fsloop:
  stmdb r2!,{r3}
  subs r0,r0,#1
  bne fsloop
  bx lr
```

the C prototype for the above is

```
void fill_stack ( unsigned int );
```

where the parameter is the number of 32 bit words you want to fill.

put the asm in some file say fill_stack.s and add that file to your compiler command line with your c programs (or assemble it separately to object and link if you dont use the c compiler that way).  inline assembly is harder and not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do this in assembly: you can do it in C

```
void stack_init(unsigned int size)
{
        int i;
        unsigned char mem[size];

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                mem[i] = 0xAA; /* Best not to use 0 or all ones */
}

unsigned int stack_check(unsigned int max)
{
        int i;
        unsigned char mem[max];

        for (i = max - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (mem[i] != 0xAA)
                        break;
        }
        return i + sizeof(int);
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that this would not do it because a large array doesn't necessarily fill up the stack in a predictable way. I was told you had to explicitly do this with inline assembly functions. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: it's possible that your compiler will place a large array on the heap rather than the stack - look at the disassembly to see what is going on - it's much easier to read than to write! And try compiling this code without optimization even if other code is optimized.